# Upstream universal package artifact feed

Tags: azure-artifacts

I am trying to add a universal package feed as upstream source for another universal package feed in a different ADO project (but same org) but I do not find in the UI the right buttons.

According to this documentation it should be possible to upstream in the same org: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Packages does not yet support upstream sources, but will very soon (no dates to share, sorry). If the docs suggest otherwise, they may have gotten out ahead of us.